# Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function case

Tags: sql-server, case

I have an issue with substring function while using it inside case statement.

```
select              
case when -1<0 then 'ok' else SUBSTRING('abcd',1,-1) end
```

gives me an issue:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.

Why is the case "looking" at the else condition since the first condition is met?

On the other hand query:

```
declare @a int;
set @a=-1

select              
@a,
case when @a<0 then 'ok' else SUBSTRING('abcd',1,@a) end
```

presents the right answer 'ok' without any errors.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the literal value of `-1` is parsed by the compiler before run-time for the length parameter. The compiler knows that `-1` is invalid, as length must have a positive value, so the error is flagged before the SQL is even run.

In the latter statement, the length passed is a variable. At compile time, the variable has an "unknown" value, as it's not `SET` till run time, thus the syntax is fine.

Simply put, the compiler knows that a length of -1 for `SUBSTRING`is invalid, regardless of if that SQL will actually run, and so errors.

Unlike other functions, such as `STUFF` and `REPLICATE`, which state *"If length is negative, a null string is returned."*, `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT` all state: *"If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned."* For a literal value, it appears that the compiler is checking these values, even if they will never be used, and then flagging the error.

This isn't limited to logic within a `CASE` either. For example, the using logical flow operators such as `IF` generates the same behaviour:

```
IF 1 = 0
    SELECT LEFT('abc',-1)
```

As does the `ISNULL` function:

```
SELECT ISNULL('ok',RIGHT('abc',-1));
```

It only, however, occurs with literal values. If, for example, you were to use the values from a column, the behaviour is not seen:

```
IF 1 = 0 
    SELECT SUBSTRING('abc',1,n) FROM (VALUES(1),(-1)) V(n);
```

This does not return an error, even though everything in `VALUES` is a literal. That is because the value of `n` has not been evaluated.

Comment: I understand the answer, but this is not a compile-time issue.

Comment: Although I've added some comments to your answer, I've added further dialogue to show how the behaviour very much points to this being when the T-SQL is parsed, and not at run time, and is certainlly not a "bug" with the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - this **is** a compile time issue. There are two different easy ways that you can tell this. First generating an estimated plan fails. Second if you add a `RETURN`  before the statement and execute the batch the error is still shown even though the batch would be exited before that statement is reached if this was a runtime issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as it needed positive end values as length can not be in negative but can be 0.

```
select              
case when -1 < 0 then 'ok' else SUBSTRING('abcd',1, 1) end
```